# Date time TryParse issue

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am reading csv file where one of tha columns has date format like tat: `Day/Month/Year` eg: `30/07/2010`

But when i am using `DateTime.TryParse()` to parse that sting in to datetinme method `TryParse()` treated first numbers like month (number 30 in example above), so i am getting incorrect date exception.

How may i say to `Datetime.TryParse()` that first numbers in string is day and not a month?

**UPDATE:**

Why if i changed date to `Month/Day/Year` eg: `7/30/2010`

this not working:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("7/30/2010", "m/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need a capital M in your format, the lower case m is meant for minutes in a time specification. Use `"M/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: @Clayton i thought i was tried that as well, ok i will look

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into using a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Also, to use a custom format string, you need to use TryParseExact, ala:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, 
                       "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method

```
DateTime dateValue;
var dateString = "30/07/2010";
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TryParseExact()` and pass the format for your date

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("30/07/2010", "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
```